# How to use sharedInstance on swift as global variable?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, viewcontroller

Is it possible to recognize a sharedinstance value defined in one class, in another class, or view controller, or even in another function?

How do you get the singleton variables here:

```
        self.user.userId = 42
        self.user.name = too as String
        println(self.user.name) // 42
```

To pass and be referenceable within this as the same variable (ex. self.user.userId will still print 42?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;
        svc.toPass = self.user.name as String
        println("he")
        println(self.user.userId)
        println(svc.toPass)}
}}
```

xcode 6.1.1 sharedinstance

I have this in a .swift file:

```
class User {
    class var sharedInstance: User {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: User?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = User()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }

    var userId: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}
```

Comment: I don't see any shared instance in this question. What does it have to do with shared instance or singleton? Do you actually know what a shared instance / singleton _is_?

Comment: matt, please see the update that includes: class User {
    class var sharedInstance: User {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: User?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
        
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = User()
        }
        
        return Static.instance!
    }
    
    var userId: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}

Comment: I need to get the value of  let too: AnyObject? = rowData ["time"] as String in a different view controller.

Comment: All of current methods I'm trying a returning nil.

Comment: Need to get values of what was clicked in cell. Currently it appears in the form of let too: AnyObject? = rowData ["time"] as String in a func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {//in here it appears properly} I need that variable to be callable as a var or string etc.. in a different view controller.

Comment: The problem is that that is not a singleton. If it were, you'd be talking in your code about `User.User`. But you aren't. You are talking about `self.user`. If this were a global singleton, yo wouldn't be saying that. You've made multiple User instances - the very opposite of a singleton.

Comment: why would this be a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't a lot of data, the strategy I use to pass data between view controllers is to store the value in `NSUserDefaults`.

**Setting A Value**: When you first get the data, store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() //This class variable needs to be defined every class where you set or fetch values from NSUserDefaults
defaults.setValue(42, forKey: "userID")
defaults.setValue("too", forKey: "username")
defaults.synchronize() //Call this when you're done editing the defaults. It saves your changes to the disk
```

**Fetching A Value**: When you need to get the values, just grab it from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let userID = defaults.objectForKey("userID") as? Int
let username = defaults.objectForKey("username") as? String
```

Doing that gives you access to the stored values in any class and allows the data to persist after the app is closed and reopened. If you want to clear the data after the app closes, in AppDelegate `applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)` function, call the [removeObjectForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/removeObjectForKey:) function for each key previously set.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.removeObjectForKey("userID")
defaults.removeObjectForKey("username")
defaults.synchronize()
```

**Helpful Source on NSUserDefaults**:

`NSUserDefulats` Class Reference: Link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

Comment: Sure thing! Please up-vote the answer too if you thought it was good.

Comment: I tried up voting you, I don't have 15 creds so I can't upgrade. If you think my question was good, please up vote it!

Comment: I forgot to add this: The final statement you should make after editing the defaults in a method is the defaults.synchronize() function. That will save all your change to the disk.